# How to Embed Facebook Page stream and Twitter Stream on Joomla Articles

Tags: facebook

Please do not flag my question without reading carefully.

I am building a site database of famous people. Each person's short biography is a joomla article. I want to embed the facebook and twitter stream of each person on their articles.

I did a lot of research and found many modules but i don't need modules, i want a plugin so that I can embed fb and twitter stream of the particular famous person on their articles (biography).

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the

```
Content - Load Modules
```

plugin to load the module into an article.

In the module settings, specify a custom position such as `myposition` and insert the module into the article using the following syntax:

```
{loadposition myposition}
```

Comment: Thank you jdog  This is a good idea but I will have to create a module for each bio article but looks like this is the only option as of now  :(